# Tried to Inline CSS with AdvAgg but still get errors in Google

Tags: css-js-aggregation

My Right-to-left site uses clean Bootstrap subtheme and has CDN, Internal caching (including [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost)), Minification, Compression and aggregation, but still I get very low grades with all that has to do with **CSS performance**. Therefore I tried to inline all the CSS in my site via AdvAgg (please see image), what helped me in another theme, but not this time...

Is there anything else you think I should try?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty good guide on how to get css to load quicker https://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/use-grunt-and-advagg-inline-critical-css-drupal-7-theme

Comment: Hello @mikeytown2 ! I did everything he said about AdvAgg... The amount of CSS errors reduced to only a single error... But this is the only error I can't solve in any way (Uploaded an image)... This error always appears... It's the only error that always appear and it's seem to be Bootstrap-CDN related, what makes it more vague to me.

Comment: Inspect your code and see what CSS is not aggregated and inlined the way you want it to. We can't see it. You can. And knowing where it came from is most important part of knowing why it avoided advagg processing.

Comment: @Mołot, I would very much like to do so but don't know how. Can you please, and with much grace, link me to an article that explains how to see what you mean to with Firebug? Ben.

Comment: @benos just Google "how to use firebug", "how to inspect CSS with firebug", things like that. Or if you prefer Chrome, substitute firebug with chrome developer tools.

Comment: Oh, there is a mistake here, I know very well how to use firebug for inspection of CSS files, see their location, editing them as preview for Style.css (with our without DOM), etc (did that for the last 5 hours). I just don't know where to see what you talked about --- Knowing from Firebug why it's not aggregated or inlined?

Comment: Another way is enabling css one by one until error occurs

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Your path is wrong. It should be `node/*`. You have `*/node`;

Comment: My path is fine --- It's just due to the fact the site is RTL (updated the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do with the CSS inlining can only happen when the CSS is coming from Drupal, internal resource. External CSS resources cannot be inlined. If you read at the top of the "Inline CSS/JS On Specific Pages" it says, "This will prevent all local CSS and/or JavaScript files...". I agree that it is somewhat subtle and might need to be highlighted better in the UI that it only works for internal resources.Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to.

[image]

The only option you have with external CSS resources with AdvAgg is to move them to the **TOP** of the page. You could move the resource to the bottom of the page via a [hook_alter_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) in a custom module. But seeing this is the bootstrap CSS I can guarantee that will render your website broken.

Unfortunately, you cannot do anything about the CSS file with Pagespeed. You could host the CSS file in your site, but then you would lose the advantage of the CDN, which I see that the rest of your site is not using a CDN. Remember that Google Pagespeed scores are only one of many benchmarks and tests you should use in making a website perform. It is best to compare many different sources of data for optimizing your site (Pagespeed, YSlow, Pingdom Page Test, Webpagetest.org, etc.) And with optimization you have to give and take, it is nearly impossible to get a perfect score because you have to make sacrifices in certain areas. Being this CSS file is on a CDN and it is minified already, the impact to your site is honestly low. If you were to move the CSS to your site so AdvAgg could inline it, it would actually be worse for your site. It is a large CSS file that is critical for rendering your website, a CDN is the best place for it! I personally have found Pagespeed to be unrealistic in it's scoring from time to time.

Comment: This is correct. The bootstrap css is external. Copy locally and use hook_alter_css to switch the external location to be local.

Comment: So, everyone who uses Boostrap CDN is doomed to have a lower Pagespeed-insights score because of that particular file? :|

Answer (score 4):

Your setting for **Inline CSS on specific pages** is wrong. The path you should set is:

```
node/*
```

Comment: It's not helping and cannot help --- My site is RTL, it's a natural flip of the language and the CSS itself is inlined --- all besides the file I mentioned... :|

Comment: It doesn't matter if your site is RTL or not. The path registered in route is `node/*`.

Comment: He is right. URL paths cannot be RTL.

Comment: Me? or Him? Anyway @ЕлинЙ, It's seems to me you are wrong here because most of the CSS does inlined! www.beniaharon.co.il, please go in, view source and see the there is inlining of the CSS even via this path.

Comment: @benos Path matching is string matching...are your node pages available at (e.g.) www.beniaharon.co.il/1/node? As in with the node ID before the `node` part? If so, then you're right, the path should be `*/node`. If not, and your paths are the regular (e.g.) www.beniaharon.co.il/node/1, it should be `node/*`. RTL doesn't come into it, unless you've somehow managed to convince Drupal to serve its node pages from an unusual path as part of your RTL conversion

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. My CSS is inlined - i.e, the path in the picture above does work. Actually all CSS is inlined besides that particular file I talk about... So, I don't understand why should the path above matter?... Can you please explain in a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Inlined CSS is a double edged-sword...

It makes the page load quicker for the first visit to a site as there are no additional http requests to load the styles. However, for subsequent visits it is actually detrimental since with non-inlined css they would then be served up from the browser cache and cause pretty much zero load delay, whereas the inlined CSS adds to the page weight and thus load time of each and every page loaded.

It can be a useful tool to prevent an HTTP request by adding a few lines of CSS to a page but I certainly wouldn't recommend it for inlining hundred or thousands of lines of CSS, unless of course you are expecting the majority of visitors to visit only one page.

I'd say a good aggregation strategy is preferable to prevent large number of CSS files from being loaded on that first page load.